# Error 0 Python PowerBI - version problem?

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, powerbi

While integrating Python code into PowerBI, I keep running into this error:

```
Details: "ADO.NET: Python script error.
<pi>KeyError: 0
</pi>"
```

This is despite the fact that code works well in Jupyter notebook. After searching through the web and trying recommended fixes e.g. launching PowerBI from activated conda environment, I'm concluding that this is due to different versions - Python 3.9 in PowerBI vs. 3.7.3 in Jupyter. This surprises me though since I only have 3.9 on my computer.

I'm happy to reproduce code but am finding that this issue isn't restricted to any single section. I've tried multiple examples of different parts of the calculation with the same end result.

I think I've been thorough in searching and not finding an answer to this problem. Apologies if this is already addressed somewhere else.

Comment: In `File -> Options -> Python Scripting`, is the 'Set a Python home directory' pointing to your Conda environment? I had an issue a bit ago where that was looking for my Windows Python env, which didn't have the same modules installed as my virtualenv.